# Where to learn LLL?

Tags: contract-development, evm

I want to support some projects of Ethereum organization, I need to know LLL but I don't fine a good doc reference, do you know some place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A great place to start is Daniel Ellison's blogs and Videos

- [The Resurrection of LLL](http://blog.syrinx.net/the-resurrection-of-lll-part-1/) - 7 parts
- An ongoing series of articles on the [ConsenSys media pages](https://media.consensys.net/@zigguratt) with links to screencasts for some of them.

I've been putting some effort into [documenting](http://lll-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) the current state-of-the-art, along with lots of examples (work in progress warning!).

You can also look at the source of a couple of contracts:

- Daniel's [ENS Registry](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/contracts/ENS.lll) (this is the ENS Registry actually deployed)
- My own [ERC20](https://github.com/benjaminion/LLL_erc20/blob/master/erc20.lll) sample.

The email addresses in the code repositories work - feel free to get in touch.

Comment: If it is of interest the ENS Registry was deployed in LLL because it was significantly quicker, and uses less gas.